# How to connect local or external mongoDB instead of meteor's internal in Rocket.chat

Tags: mongodb, rocket.chat

Rocket.Chat Version: 0.56.0-develop

Running Instances: 1

DB Replicaset OpLog: Enabled

Node Version: v4.8.1

I cloned the git code and started rocket chat in my local machine Windods 7 by following instructions as bellow.

```
git clone https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.git
cd Rocket.Chat
meteor npm start
```

Now, I want during development my app to use my local mongoDB installation instead of meteors's internal. I tried a lot but did not get any help or clue. It seems I am missing somewhere. I attaching the screen of what I changed, I hope I am doing the right. I did changed in docker-compose.yml.

[image]

Comment: First of all, the `docker-compose.yml` is only for Docker solution, but you are close. Rocketchat using `env` for connection setting to MongoDB.
I dont know how set `env` on Win7, but you can use this manual https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/windows-server#node-packages for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right I also don't know how to set env.

Comment: Friend, did you solve the problem, if yes, please post an answer. At the end helping the community is helping yourself